# Union of Index of Many Dataframes

Tags: pandas, dataframe

```
b.index = c1.index.union(c2.index).union(c3.index).union(c4.index).union(c5.index).union(c6.index).union(c7.index).union(c8.index).union(c9.index).union(c10.index)
```

I have dataframes c1 to c10 and want to create a new dataframe b that has the union index of all the dataframes. So far this is how I would do it, but I'm wondering if there's a more elegant solution.

How can I also define a function that allows me to take the index of a new dataframe c11 and add this on to b?

Comment: What is reason ? Why do it?

Comment: are duplicates in `index`es ?

Comment: Yes there are duplicates. But the index are dates and I don't need them to be duplicated.

Comment: My solution working?

Comment: Yes it works. So I just def a function that adds a dataframe to dfs to generate my required basis then..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:

```
dfs = [c1, c2, c3, ..., c10]

from functools import reduce

out = reduce(np.union1d, [x.index for x in dfs])
```

Comment: On a side note, this method will not respect duplicate indexes and will return a non-duplicate union of indexes.